# How can you find the first break in a sequence of integer numbers?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, integer

Imagine you have the following Table:

```
create table #myvalues(mykey int primary key)
```

You also have the following values:

```
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(1)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(2)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(4)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(5)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(6)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(8)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(10)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(11)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(12)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(15)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(17)
insert into #myvalues(mykey) values(20)
```

You also have a current value:

```
declare @currentvalue int

select @currentvalue = 5
```

I want to find the first break in this sequence that occurs after the @currentvalue. In this case the answer would be 7.

I could use a table variable and spin throught the records using a while loop, but there must be a better way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What sql-server version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005. I just updated the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH list
AS
(
    SELECT  myKey,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myKey ASC) rn
    FROM    #myvalues
)
SELECT  TOP 1 rn
FROM    list
WHERE   myKey <> rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49ed9/4)

here's the query that takes up `starting value`

```
DECLARE @currentValue INT 
SET @currentValue = 5

;WITH list
AS
(
    SELECT  myKey,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myKey ASC) + (@currentValue - 1) rn
    FROM    myvalues
    WHERE   myKey >= @currentValue 
)
SELECT  TOP 1 rn 
FROM    list
WHERE   myKey <> rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with starting number*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49ed9/20)

Comment: Does not take `currentvalue` into account. It would also yield incorrect results on the second gap.

Comment: If you change `currentValue` to 8 the correct result should be 13 (imho).

Comment: @TimSchmelter i think it's `9` when the starting value is `8`. let's refer to the OP

Comment: what's the problem @codingguy3000?

Answer (score 2):

You can join the table with itself:

```
select top 1 t.mykey + 1
from myvalues t
left join myvalues x on x.mykey = t.mykey + 1
where t.mykey > @currentvalue and x.mykey is null
order by t.mykey
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6dd2/7

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 myKey+1 from #myvalues
where 
    (myKey+1) not in (select mykey from #myvalues)
    and mykey >= @currentValue
```

Comment: when i tried this solution why is it that it is returning `13` instead of `9` when the starting value is `8`?

Comment: I missed that error. I tested it on my production data and it worked because the gaps were larger than 1.

Comment: Fixed: all it needed was >= instead of >